# how to import sequence diagram saved in uml format from argouml to staruml

Tags: argouml, staruml

I drew a sequence diagram in argo uml and saved it in .uml extension. It failed to generate a collaboration diagram from sequence diagram. So I started to draw in staruml. But I'm finding it difficult to import sequence diagram  from argouml to staruml. Please help me.

Comment: It'd help if you can include the error message you get when you try to generate a collaboration diagram.

Answer (score 0):

Back when these tools were built, there was no standard for interchange of the diagrams -- only the metadata.  If StarUML supports UML 1.4/1.5 you should be able to export an XMI file from ArgoUML to at least get the basics over, but the diagrams will have to be redrawn.